# Is there a portable way in standard C++ to retrieve hostname?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

I'm working on a C++ program that needs to use the hostname of the computer it is running on. My current method of retrieving this is by mangling a C API like this:

```
char *host = new char[1024];
gethostname(host,1024);
auto hostname = std::string(host);
delete host;
```

Is there a portable modern C++ method for doing this, without including a large external library (e.g., boost)?

Comment: Looks like that's a Linux call (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html). Is your goal to have the code run cross-platform? On what OS's? Windows, Mac, and Linux?

Comment: @NathanOliver, although short, you should make that an answer, no?

Comment: Tactical note: Since you know the lifespan and size of  the buffer pointed at by `host` there is no need for dynamic allocation. `char host[1024];` should be easier on pretty much everyone and everything involved.

Comment: As of C++20, standard C++ has no concept that such a thing as a hostname even exists.

Comment: Currently this only needs to run on Linux, thus the gethostname call, but it'd be nice to have a portable method.

Comment: Good point about the dynamic allocation, it is indeed unnecessary.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Done.

Comment: If that's Linux only, 1024 is a bit much, HOST_NAME_MAX is 64 for Linux, see the man page.

Comment: Nearest Windows fit is probably [`GetComputerName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcomputernamea) This and `gethostname` are pretty similar, so wrapping them is pretty easy. All bets are off for other OSes, of course.

Comment: nothing's wrong with that, but it's still using the underlying C api, just a different way of going about it

Comment: @BarmakShemirani `s.size()` may return a number that's... unfortunate. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/ov9qYGxnc

Comment: @user4581301, Ouch. I forgot about that part. I think it needs more hack `auto end = s.find('\0'); if(end != std::string::npos) s.resize(end);`

Comment: `gethostname` is POSIX. So it is essentially portable to any OS with a host name, except windows.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani or just good old `strlen`. Also docs imply that function can fail if size is too big. so probably have to use `HOST_NAME_MAX`  and check return value of `gethostname`. After all, computer may have none or an empty host name as well if it wasn't set, Less common in modern  out-of-box setups, but bare minimum system may have it not set.

Comment: [`gethostname()` is available on Windows, too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-gethostname)

Comment: @dratenik, I'd use 256 bytes, as it could be up to 255 bytes plus a null terminator on some systems. [From here in the "Notes" section](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html): "SUSv2 guarantees that "Host names are limited to 255 bytes".
       POSIX.1 guarantees that "Host names (not including the
       terminating null byte) are limited to HOST_NAME_MAX bytes".  On
       Linux, HOST_NAME_MAX is defined with the value 64, which has been
       the limit since Linux 1.0 (earlier kernels imposed a limit of 8
       bytes)" At a *minimum* you need `65` bytes (64+null).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no standard C++ support for this. You'll either have to make your own function, or get a library that has this functionality.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. It's unfortunate but looks like there isn't another way currently.

Comment: At least until the C++ standard adds its own networking library in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string>
//#include <winsock.h>      //Windows
//#include <unistd.h>       //Linux

std::string GetHostName(void)
{

    std::string res = "unknown";
    char tmp[0x100];
    if( gethostname(tmp, sizeof(tmp)) == 0 )
    {
        res = tmp;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Please add comment on your post which clarify the code

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Can this simple code be more clear?